# Simulating a large viewstate (for demo purposes) in webforms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am going to show the difference between a postback and a jQuery ajax call for some people who have never used jQuery.

When I create a new webforms project, a postback is barely noticeable. Do you have any suggestions on how to simulate a slow page with a huge viewsatate? Or anything else that could show the strengts of an AJAX call vs posting the whole page (form) back to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable ViewState on a GridView and bind several thousand records at once. That will create an incredible amount of ViewState. If that's not sufficient, just take a huge DataTable and save it in ViewState. Something like:

```
DataTable dt = GetDataTableWithThousandsOfRows();
ViewState["Data"] = dt;
```

Now look at the ViewState when the page is rendered.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I\ve never used datatables though. Got time to show me how the `GetDataTableWithThousandsOfRows` could work?